# Is acoustic pressure a statistical term?

Tags: pressure

Is acoustic pressure a statistical term? Also, what about pressure in a liquid or a gas?

Comment: What do you mean by "a statistical term"?

Comment: by statistical term i mean a physical quatity defined as a statistical nature of some physical system. Like for example temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any notion of pressure at least normally assumes that there are many, $N\to\infty$, particles that are the sources of the pressure, so in this sense it is a statistical term. But just like with the temperature, one may assign pressure or temperature to a single particle, too, although for a single particle, we would usually say that it's an accident that it has one momentum or energy or another, so there's still some reason to say that it's a statistical term.